# TikZ-Feynman: edge label puts symbols one on top of the other

Tags: tikz-feynman

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}    
\feynmandiagram [small, horizontal=a to t1] {
    a [particle=\(q\)] -- [scalar] t1 -- [fermion, edge label=\(k_1\)] t2 -- [fermion, edge label=\(k\)] t3 -- [fermion, edge label=\(k_2\)] t1,
    t2 -- [photon] p1 [particle=\(p_1\,\mu\)],
    t3 -- [photon] p2 [particle=\(p_2\,\nu\)],
    p1 -- [opacity=0.01] p2,
    }; 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The momenta are all in the same place, how can I fix this? I just would like for them to be separated from each other.

Comment: Did you try `label'=\(k_1\)` to place the label on the other side of the edge?

Comment: I tried it now but it doesn't recognize it: "I do not know the key '/tikz/label'', to which you passed '\(k\)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it"

Comment: And label without the ' make disappear the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting `edge label'` instead of just `edge label` fixes the problem.

Comment: That's what I told you ^^

Comment: At first I thought you meant label' without edge! Thank you